# How to select data in Tarantool?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I have created a space with two indexes:

```lua
box.schema.sequence.create('user_seq', { if_not_exists = true })
box.schema.create_space('users', { if_not_exists = true, format={
    { name = 'id', type = 'unsigned'},
    { name = 'name', type = 'string'}, 
    { name = 'age', type = 'unsigned'}} 
})
box.space.users:create_index('pk', { parts = { 'id' }, if_not_exists = true })
box.space.users:create_index('age', { parts = { 'age' }, if_not_exists = true })
```

Have inserted some records :

```yaml
box.space.users:insert({ box.sequence.user_seq:next(), 'Artur Barsegyan', 24})
box.space.users:insert({ box.sequence.user_seq:next(), 'Kostya Nazarov', 32})
```

How I should select data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to iterate by an index, you should call a `pairs` method on the needed index. For example:

```lua
for _, tuple in box.space.users.index.age:pairs({30}, { iterator = 'LT' }) do
    print(tuple)
end
```

You will get the following result:

```yaml
[1, 'Artur Barsegyan', 24]
---
...
```

What did we do? We have iterated by index `age` by all tuples with the `age` that less than 30. More details about iterators and other parameters and filters are [in the documentation.](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_index/#lua-function.index_object.pairs)

If you want to select all tuples in a space, call `pairs` method on space object without parameters:

```yaml
tarantool> for i, tuple in box.space.users:pairs() do
         > print(tuple)
         > end
[1, 'Artur', 'Barsegyan', 24, {'gender': 'male', 'position': 'Product Manager'}]
[2, 'Kostya', 'Nazarov', 32, {'gender': 'male', 'position': 'Lead of Tarantool Solutions'}]
---
...
```

Explore more parameters and filters [in documentation](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_space_index/#lua-function.space_object.pairs) and in the following SO questions:

- [Can there be any problems deleting records when iterating over them in Tarantool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716512/can-there-be-any-problems-deleting-records-when-iterating-over-them-in-tarantool)
- [How do I select a limited number of records from tarantool, like with SELECT LIMIT in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56584050/how-do-i-select-a-limited-number-of-records-from-tarantool-like-with-select-lim/56584208#56584208)

Answer (score 0):

Why not do things the easy way?

```lua
box.schema.space.create "users"
box.space.users:format { { name="id", type="unsigned"} --[[and so on]] }
box.space.users:create_index("primary", { sequence = true })
box.space.users:insert { nil, "John Doe", 20 }
box.space.users:insert { nil, "Jon Snow", 20 }

local all_users = box.space.users:select()
```